# bash: Filtering out directories and extensions from find?

Tags: bash, find

I'm trying to find files modified recently with this

```
find . -mtime 0
```

Which gives me

```
en/content/file.xml
es/file.php
en/file.php.swp
css/main.css
js/main.js
```

But I'd like to filter out the `en` and `es` directories but would like to grab anything else. In addition, I'd like to filter out `.swp` files from the results of those.

So I want to get back:

```
css/main.css
js/main.js
xml/foo.xml
```

In addition to every other file not within `es/en` and not ending in `.swp`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

properly, just in find:

```
find -mtime 0 -not \( -name '*.swp' -o -path './es*' -o -path './en*' \)
```

Comment: Good answer! find is great but the implementation in various UNIX versions differs, so I prefer solutions that are easier to memorize and using more commands with standard options

Comment: I can agree with that, but looking at the OP's tags and rep I figured `grep` was known and not an option. Keeping it within `find` allows for way more flexible output/actions (`-exec`, `-ls`, `-print0`, `-printf`, ...)

Comment: (btw the tag `bash` implies GNU)

Comment: -exec -ls -print are very well known and personally I used them in AIX with almost no difference. My point is: it is hard to memorize the 'little bit' complex matching and modifiers options of find command while other simple and easy to memorize options exist.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
find . -mtime 0 | grep -v '^en' | grep -v '^es'
```

Adding the ***cap*** character at the beginning of the pattern given to grep ensures that it is a must to find the pattern at the start of the line.

**Update:** Following [Chen Levy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110488/chen-levy) comment(s), use the following instead of the above

```
find . -mtime 0 | grep -v '^\./en' | grep -v '^\./es'
```

find is great but the implementation in various UNIX versions differs, so I prefer solutions that are easier to memorize and using commands with more standard options

Comment: Anchoring the patterns do make it a little more robust.  I updated my answer to match.

Comment: Please see my comment for @speshak's answer. Also find can do this work without the help of grep.

Comment: You are almost there. Note that `.` is significant in a regex, try `\.` instead, and then you can revert to your initial answer of matching beginning of line with `^\./es`.

Answer (score 3):

The `-prune` command prevents find form descending down the directories you wish to avoid:

```
find . \( -name en -o -name es \) -prune , -mtime 0 ! -name "*.swp"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -mtime 0 | grep -v '^en' | grep -v '^es' | grep -v .swp
```

The -v flag for grep makes it return all lines that *don't* match the pattern.

Comment: This might not work correctly: The output of `find .` will return lines that starts with `./` and thus the `grep -v "^e..." will not match, and thus will not filter the unwanted lines.

Answer (score 0):

The -regex option of find(1) (which can be combined with the -E option to enable extended regular expressions) matches the whole file path as well.

```
find . -mtime 0 -not \( -name '*.swp' -o -regex '\./es.*' -o -regex '\./en.*' \)
find "$(pwd -P)" -mtime 0 -not \( -name '*.swp' -o -regex '.*/es.*' -o -regex '.*/en.*' \)
```